# How to use Speech 2 Text in Microsoft Surface

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, pixelsense, speech-to-text

I'd like to use some speech 2 text in my microsoft surface application. I saw that it is possible, but I don't really know where to start. Is there any framework/library available, or a code snippet, or a tutorial??

I don't even know exactly what i should google for ;)

===EDIT===
I read that it is necessary to use a grammar to recognize words. So if I want to proceed free text, is there a predefined grammar for the english language? Or is it a better choice to don't use speech2text but just audio files instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speech recognition is part of the .NET framework since Version 3.0. Look at the System.Speech.Recognition namespace.

Comment: Thanks. I read that it is necessary to use a grammar to recognize words. So if I want to proceed free text, is there a predefined grammar for the english language? Or is it a better choice to don't use speech2text but just audio files instead?

Comment: Now I'm not sure what you mean, since you mentioned "audio files": Are you asking about Speech To Text, or Text to Speech?